# Need help setting up Ubuntu 14.04 Router/firewall

Tags: 14.04, dns, firewall, router, gateway

This is my first post here.

Out of desperation - despite reading lots and lots of step-through guides, tutorials and other threads with similar problems - I can't seem to get my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS router to work properly. With each problem I solve, I seem to create another and I feel I'm digging myself deeper into a hole. I'm learning fast, but no advanced user, so please be gentle with me.

Here's what I'm trying to do:
Build a router/firewall/squid box - a gateway for my private network - which also runs as a file server.

**internet..>..modem/router..>..linux router/firewall..>..airport extreme**

eth0 = External NIC - DHCP (getting IP from modem/router)
eth1 = Internal NIC - static 192.168.0.25 (providing DHCP to int network)
modem/router = 192.168.0.1

Services I'm running:
webmin, isc-dhcp-server, ssh, squid, ufw, seafile

Services I've removed:
network-manager

Here's some problems I'm having (more detailed info below):
1. eth1 keeps being allocated an IP despite being set to static
2. I'm not always able to ping eth1 (192.168.0.25) from internal network
3. When booting I get "waiting for network configuration", until "Booting system without full network configuration"
4. When I can get eth0 to ping modem/router and connect to internet, it's still not passing traffic through (from eth1 > eth0)
5. I've tried with/without ufw and after flushing iptables
6. I'm also getting an error ".local domain is incompatible with avadhi". I use [server name].local:10000 to connect to webmin, will that cause a problem?

When I bypass the router (IE. eth1..>..switch..>..modem/router..>..internet) I can ping into my linux box and access ssh (set up RSA keys).

Here's some more detailed info of my setup:

```
$ route -n  
Kernel IP routing table  
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface  
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1  
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth1  
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1  
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

(Where is the 169.xxx.xxx.xxx IP coming from?? Modem/router is set to give a range of 192.168.0.100-192.168.0.150)

I have in:$ /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.0.25
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
    network 192.168.0.0
    hwaddress ether 00:16:cb:aa:c6:d9
    dns-nameservers 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220 211.29.132.12 198.142.0.51
```

Here's my DNS settings (from my ISP and OpenDNS):

```
/etc/resolv.conf

 Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
nameserver 211.29.132.12
```

In:$ /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=00:16:CB:AA:C6:D9,00:E0:4C:53:44:5B,

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

Here's from:$ /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       server

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

In:$ /etc/sysctl.conf I've uncommented

```
# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

And for masquerading I ran the long script "4.5. Enable IP forwarding and Masquerading" from here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router

I suspect it's a dsnmasq or DNS/gateway problem and I don't fully comprehend how that all works, but to be honest I don't know enough to trouble shoot it all. Or has removing network-manager caused problems? Or is wicd causing me grief?

Please help, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think it must be Ubuntu. I've set this up previously many times using SuSE and it was a breeze. Ubuntu 14.04 seems to be much more hobbled together, with all sorts of unstable an conflicting services.

If only I could get SuSE to install on my old MacMini.